# auto_ptr, immediate get() and release() - is it useful?

Tags: c++

I'm working on someone else's code that contains lots of statements like this

```
std::auto_ptr<ObjectA> smartptr(new ObjectA(this));
objects_list.push_back(smartptr.get());
smartptr.release();
```

Is this even useful? Is there some practical reason to use a smart pointer here instead of just writing

```
objects_list.push_back(new ObjectA(this));
```

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is useful. It's just not that usable.

Comment: What if `object_list` throws when regrowing? Also, `std::auto_ptr` is C++03, so I removed the C++11 tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
objects_list.push_back(new ObjectA(this));
```

This can leak memory. Let's see what happens when we break it down:

- `new ObjectA(this)` is allocated
- `push_back` is then called

However, `push_back` can throw and if it does, your `new ObjectA` is leaked.

The `auto_ptr` code you showed us solves this problem: if `push_back` throws then the pointer is still owned by `auto_ptr` and no leak happens.

---

The real solution would be to store smart pointers directly in the container instead of naked pointers (because naked pointers in containers are a headache when it comes to ensuring the objects are correctly deleted).

Unfortunately with C++03 (which is where `auto_ptr` comes from, it's been deprecated in C++11) this is not possible to store `auto_ptr` in containers (the pattern is badly broken). One could store `boost::shared_ptr` in containers, or switch to C++11 and store either `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea was probably to guard against memory leaks in case the vector's `push_back` throws. This might happen if the vectors needs to be relocated and fails to allocate more memory.

Comment: Or if copy / move ctors of the objects throw.

Comment: Xeo: If a copy or move of a pointer value throws you're screwed anyway

Comment: Who says that `object_list` actually stores pointers? Maybe it stores something that is implicitly constructible from `ObjectA*`? :)

Comment: That's a valid point. But if the vector contained a smart pointer why not
construct that immediately? Otherwise I am not sure one should reason too much
about this code base.

Comment: @honk: "*If a copy or move of a pointer value throws you're screwed anyway*" => smart pointer constructors/assignment are `noexcept`, and copying/moving integral types (eg. a naked pointer) cannot throw either. So your hypothetical situation cannot arise.

Comment: @syam: So you agree with me that in that case you would be screwed then? ;) Note that Xeo clarified later how this can realistically throw in move or copt ctors.

Answer (score 1):

It provides exception safety. In the first example, the allocated object will be deleted if `push_back` fails; in the second example, it will leak.

Note that, since 2011, `auto_ptr` is deprecated in favour of `unique_ptr`. That has the advantage that it can be stored in the vector, relieving you of the burden of manually deleting the objects when removing them from the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Auto_ptr is useful to handle memory leakage.Please find below link for more info on auto pointer.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23670/auto_ptr-and-its-usage